# Difference between infinitive phrase and gerund phrase as subject

Tags: gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund, infinitive-phrases

What's the difference in meaning between these two sentences:

> **To find fault** with others is easy.
>
> **Finding fault** with others is easy.

Also more generally, what's the difference between infinitive phrase and gerund phrase as the subject with other verbs. More examples would help.

Comment: There is no real difference in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Both these sentences are correct and there's no actual difference in meaning here, but typically using the gerund is preferred when putting a phrase like this in the subject position.

Answer (score 0):

I would say word order.  If you're using an infinitive I would structure it this way -

It is easy to find fault with others. 
Finding fault with others is easy.

The second sentence is perfectly acceptable, but word order for the first sentence sounds more natural if you don't start with the infinitive.